# How to disallow exception to curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures linter rule in dart?

Tags: dart, static-analysis

Dart linter rule [curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures) states:

> There is one exception to this: an if statement with no else clause where the entire if statement and the body all fit in one line. In that case, you may leave off the braces if you prefer

I want to disable this exception and require that all flow control structures require curly braces without exception.

How can I configure the linter to disallow this exception?

Comment: You can't customize a specific lint like that, but if you add the rule [always_put_control_body_on_new_line](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/always_put_control_body_on_new_line) you should a lint warning in that scenario.